# Color encoding when using `:! <command>`

Tags: vim, macvim

When I run, for example, `! yarn lint` inside a MacVim. I have this result.

[image]

While I run the same command in Terminal's Vim. This is what I get.

[image]

Is there any way to make the former colourised as the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I followed [romainl's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65771821/459794) and came up with a solution.

First, `:terminal ++close yarn format` does colour the terminal result nicely, so I updated my mapping.

```
map <Leader>l :terminal ++close yarn format<CR>
```

Then to fix the auto-reload problem. This is what I did.

```
set autoread
au CursorHold,CursorHoldI * checktime
au FocusGained,BufEnter * :checktime
```

Thanks to resources from this thread!

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149209/refresh-changed-content-of-file-opened-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

The shell used by the MacVim GUI for `:!` commands is a so-called "dumb shell" that doesn't support styling at all so you can't have colors, there. If you absolutely need styled output, use the built-in `:help :terminal`.

That said, command-line utilities are expected to know when and when not to use styling. Since the ones you use appear to output escape sequence when they shouldn't, it might be a good idea to notify their maintainers of that flaw.

Comment: This almost works for me! But the problem is not the formatted file doesn't get automatically reloaded. I've tried `:terminal yarn format \| :edit` and it still doesn't work …

Comment: @PatWangrungarun This is another problem entirely that, I think, has been asked about many times in the past. Use the site's search feature or ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing the different color schemes is because the Terminal and MacVim editor each have their own application-specific configurations, which includes the theme. However, it is possible to unify the two applications to share the same Vim settings in a `.vimrc` file.  The default `.vimrc` that MacVim looks for is located under `$HOME/.vimrc`, and the same goes for the Terminal’s version of Vim.  If you like the dark background that is being used in the Terminal’s Vim, you can set it with:

```sh
set background=dark
```

I also highly recommend you read up, at least to a basic understanding, on the `.vimrc` [settings](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Example_vimrc).

There are also some good examples out there:

- https://gist.github.com/simonista/8703722
- https://github.com/amix/vimrc/tree/master/vimrcs

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I wasn't concern about the colour schemes though. Take a look at the lower image you'll see a line `$ yarn format-scss && yarn format-js` in a gray-ish colour–not white. While the upper image you'll see `[2K[1G[2m$ yarn format-scss && yarn format-js[22m`. So I think the `[2K[1G[2m` part is kind of a colour encoding, which works in Terminal but doesn't work in MacVim's quickfix window.